# Template argument with the name of a class in another namespace

Tags: visual-c++

In VC++ 2013 (and 2015 RC), I find that this results in compilation errors:

```
namespace namespace1
{
    template<typename T>
    class Bar
    {};
}

namespace namespace2
{
    template <unsigned Bar>
    struct Foo
    {
        static const int value = (Bar < 1) ? 1 : 2;
    };
}
```

Errors:

```
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
: see reference to class template instantiation 'namespace2::Foo<Bar>' being compiled
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
fatal error C1201: unable to continue after syntax error in class template definition
```

If I swap the order of the namespaces, I don't get an error.

Why is the compiler treating Bar as a type, when it's not qualified with the namespace?

Additionally, if I change the value initialisation to:

```
static const int value = (Bar > 1) ? 1 : 2;
```

I don't get an error either.

Encountered this while compiling Google Protocol Buffers, where this struct definition:

```
// Compile-time equivalent of VarintSize32().
template <unsigned Value>
struct StaticVarintSize32 {
    static const int value =
        (Value < (1 << 7))
            ? 1
            : (Value < (1 << 14))
                ? 2
                : (Value < (1 << 21))
                     ? 3
                    : (Value < (1 << 28))
                         ? 4
                         : 5;
};
```

won't compile due to a template class called Value existing in a namespace in our own codebase. I have worked around it for now by ensuring that the relevant Procotol Buffers header is included first, but it seems that this is a compiler bug?

Is there any other way to fix it, when I can't really change either Protocol Buffers code or the Value class?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. `Bar` the class template is not visible at the point where `Bar` is used. As a workaround, you can put an extra pair of parens around `Bar`, as in `static const int value = ( (Bar) < 1) ? 1 : 2;`

Comment: As mentioned, that's in the protocol buffers code, and whilst I can change it, I don't think it's the right fix.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed as a bug by Microsoft, will be fixed in 2015 RTM.